# Angular 2 - Open up a component after Button Click

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to Angular 2 and Type Script. I am developing an application using Angular 2, Web API and ASP.NET MVC 5.
In my application, I have a grid component (grid.component) which renders as below.[image]

Once the user click on the EDIT button the edit component (edit.component) should be opened.
Below is my HTML code for the button click.

```html
<button title="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editRecord(record.Id)">Edit</button>
```

What should be the code goes inside the event handler code to open up the edit component. My event handler code is below.

```js
editRecord(id: number) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Standard way to do this is to open a dialog with angular-bootstrap, angular-material or another framework, or to navigate to another route with the @angular/router. I think you will not get a much better answer, because the question is too general :-)

Comment: Yes. I think I need to study @angular/router.